# Unable to pull local docker images - Windows

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, kubernetes-helm

When I do a `docker images`, I am able to see the image I created :

```
rmq-iv            latest              673510273796
```

But when I do a : `docker pull rmq-iv :latest`, I get:

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for rmq-iv, repository
>   does not exist or may require 'docker login'

I get the same error when I try the image tag in my helm chart. My aim is just to pull the image, is there something wrong I'm doing or some Windows specific setting I might need to do to get this working?

My helm chart which uses the image:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cache-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: dep
          value: "1"
        image: rmq-iv:latest
        name: scs
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: Why would you pull an image that is already stored locally? Pull tries to fetch the image from a repository and store it locally.

Comment: @Henry I would want to use it in my docker-compose - but then I get this error. Helm charts specifically

Comment: Can you show the compose file?

Comment: Helm charts? Are you using Kubernetes?

Comment: @Henry Yes, I have updated with the helm chart I'm using

Comment: I managed to tag my image, push it to our private registry and then pull from it. But it would have been good to take it from local without all this hassle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images have to be pulled from a docker registry. You can either use a public registry, or you can set up a private one. There is no such thing as "local pull".